# How to set write rule for specific value

Tags: android, firebase

I'm developing an Android app using the firebase. There is a"Score" for each user.

```
user:
    $uid:
     "Score":100
```

Like that.

Only admin can read and write "Score". User can only read it. But when the user breaks rules or policies, his score will be reduced automatically. But the problem is if I set write permission to false ,score cannot be reduced. 
I want to set a write true if the score is increased by admin and write false in the score is reduced.
 Are there some opinions about this problem?

Comment: You should do something in `onFailureListener` when he tries to write or update his score there.

Comment: Can you explain me in details?

Comment: Do you want to reduce his score (in another child) or set the value to false in the restricted child?

Comment: I want to set the new reduced score in the same child node. But my rule prevent him from writing that node by himself.

Comment: This is not possible, you can allow him to only access his own score child (to write there) if you want to keep his score there, otherwise, you may need to use `cloud functions` to do so.